# How can I plot implicit functions in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I have a two-variables function as

```
Z = m_1 m_2 / pow(m_1 + m_2, 2)
```

I want to plot the curves with constant values for `Z` in the `m_1 - m_2` plane (contours). For example, `Z=0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25`. What is the easiest way to do this job in python via matplotlib? Following is what I've tried but it doesn't quite what I want. I expect different results. I need to make sure if this is correct.

```
def etta(m_1, m_2):
    return m_1*m_2 / pow(m_1 + m_2, 2)

m_1 = linspace(4, 14, 100)
m_2 = linspace(4, 14, 100)

X,Y = meshgrid(m_1, m_2)

Z = etta(X, Y).T

print(sqrt(2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cnt = contour(Z, cmap=cm.RdBu)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty standard contour problem (isn't it?).  Do you have any code that we could take a look at to see what isn't working?

Comment: I added my code. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Your code produces what I would have expected.  You can also visualize it with `imshow(Z, origin='lower') to compare.  What did you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
V = [0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25]
cnt = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, V, cmap=cm.RdBu)
```

Which will draw lines at values given by `V`.  The problem though, is that the values you gave mostly don't show up in the domain given by `X` and `Y`.  You can see this by looking at the full function with `imshow`:

```
plt.imshow(Z, extent=(X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()), origin='lower', cmap=cm.RdBu)
```

[image: imshow]

[image: contour]

Increase the values in `V` to see more lines:

```
V = np.linspace(.1, .3, 25)
plt.contour(X,Y,Z,V, cmap=cm.RdBu)
```

[image]